# How do I use the SPARQL BIND in hsparql?

Tags: haskell, bind, sparql

I would like someone to show how the BIND from SPARQL can be used in haskell hsparql module.

I have the following query;

select ?t
where {
 BIND (5 as ?t)
}

How what can be the equivalent in haskell using hsparql?

I checked the examples on the the page https://github.com/robstewart57/hsparql/blob/master/tests/DBPedia.hs but found nothing which directly addresses my query.

Thanks.

Comment: If hsparql only covers SPARQL 1.0, there is no way to set the value of a variable except from the data (i.e a triple pattern).